# Calculate a field's value based on multiple records in another table in Access DB

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, calculated-field

I'm trying to create a database in Access 2010, and have run into a bit of a problem.  I currently have two tables, `EarlyStageListResults` & `ESDailyTotals`.  Each of these tables has a field named `Records`, with `ESDailyTotals` being a summary of multiple entries in `EarlyStageListResults`.  What I need to do is have the `Records` field in `ESDailyTotals` be the sum of multiple `Records` fields in `EarlyStageListResults`.  For example, given the following records in `EarlyStageListResults`:

```
Date          Records
4/22/16       2000
4/22/16       3000
4/22/16       1500
4/21/16       1200
4/21/16       2700
```

the records in `ESDailyTotals` should be:

```
Date          Records
4/22/16       6500
4/21/16       3900
```

I know this can be calculated later through VBA and a form event, but optimally I'd like to be able to have it update as soon as any of the `Records` fields in `EarlyStageListResults` changes.  It looks like there may be a way to do this using the Access Macro Editor (not sure of the name, but the tool where you can create a macro through a series of combo boxes rather than through VBA), but I've never gotten an understanding of using that tool, so have always relied on Forms and VBA instead.  Basically if there's an event that triggers when a field is updated, and a way to enter VBA code into that event handler like you can with Access Forms, then I can do it with either DLookup or an SQL statement I think, but I don't know how to grab that event handler.

This does all need to be done within Access itself, I can't use an external program to update the records in an Access database file.  This is for work, and (officially at least) any custom programs are a big no-no.  :)

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this way too complicated.  You just need one table and a database view (called a query in Access, I think) that is defined as

```
select Date, sum(Records) as Records from EarlyStageListResults
group by Date
```

Name the query `ESDailyTotals`.

Comment: That won't update the field though right?  The reason I need them totalled is that there are calculations that need to be done using the total number per day.  I've had this working in a different form before, what I'm trying to do is simplify it.  The prior version had these two tables combined as a single table, and it works that way, but then I need around 10 fields for each list, and if a list name changes then I have to go in and change the fields, which means previous data is much more difficult to access.  I'm trying to make it more updateable for future changes.

Comment: `That won't update the field though right?` I don't know what this means, or what field you are referring to.  It's a query, it's going to calculate the totals on the fly every time `ESDailyTotals` is accessed.

Comment: I need the results of the calculation to be stored in the `ESDailyTotals` `Report` field so it can be accessed in later calculations.  There's a field named `PercentTotal` that stores the percent of all accounts that a specific list contains each day.  If there's a total of 6000 accounts on a given day, and List A contains 2000 of those, then List A's `PercentTotal` field would be 33%. (continued)

Comment: In order to calculate that, I need a field that shows the number of accounts in List A, and the total accounts in Lists A, B, C & D.  So I need to add all the `EarlyStageListResults.Record` fields from a given day to be added and that value stored in `ESDailyTotals.Records`.

Comment: Maybe as an alternative then, is there a way within Access to store the results of a query into a field?

Comment: A query acts exactly like a table -- you can use it as a report source, join it to other tables/queries, etc.  The only difference is you (usually) can't edit queries.  You can dump the contents of a query into a table, but why would you want to given the above?  But you're now asking other questions and referring to tables/fields that were never mentioned in your original question, and comments is not a good place to do that.